# Heap-based buffer overflow in Sudo vulnerability - sudo version impacted?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, vulnerability

I have some servers running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

In last update of sudo package I can see that `sudo:amd64 1.8.21p2-3ubuntu1.4` has been installed on 26/01/2021 (the same day that [Heap-based buffer overflow in Sudo vulnerability, CVE-2021-3156](https://blog.qualys.com/vulnerabilities-research/2021/01/26/cve-2021-3156-heap-based-buffer-overflow-in-sudo-baron-samedit)  was published)

As per [this list](https://www.cybersecurity-help.cz/vdb/SB2021012632) , sudo version 1.8.21p2 is impacted by this vulnerability.

However, if I run the test command to check if the systems are vulnerable, I get:

```
# sudoedit -s /
usage: sudoedit [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] file ...
```

Which is the output when the system is not impacted by this vulnerability.

Are my systems vulnerables or not ? Is there any incongruence between the versions list and the command output ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of versions you’re looking at only documents versions of `sudo` released by the `sudo` project itself. Distributions such as Ubuntu typically add patches to address such security vulnerabilities, instead of upgrading to the latest version of `sudo`.

To determine whether your version is affected, you need to look at [the security information provided by your distribution](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices); in this instance, the relevant notice is [USN-4705-1](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4705-1), which indicates that your version is fixed.

You can also look at the package changelog, in `/usr/share/doc/sudo/changelog.Debian.gz`; this should list the CVEs addressed by the version currently installed on your system (if any):

```
  * SECURITY UPDATE: dir existence issue via sudoedit race
    - debian/patches/CVE-2021-23239.patch: fix potential directory existing
      info leak in sudoedit in src/sudo_edit.c.
    - CVE-2021-23239
  * SECURITY UPDATE: heap-based buffer overflow
    - debian/patches/CVE-2021-3156-pre1.patch: check lock record size in
      plugins/sudoers/timestamp.c.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2021-3156-pre2.patch: sanity check size when
      converting the first record to TS_LOCKEXCL in
      plugins/sudoers/timestamp.c.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2021-3156-1.patch: reset valid_flags to
      MODE_NONINTERACTIVE for sudoedit in src/parse_args.c.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2021-3156-2.patch: add sudoedit flag checks in
      plugin in plugins/sudoers/policy.c.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2021-3156-3.patch: fix potential buffer overflow
      when unescaping backslashes in plugins/sudoers/sudoers.c.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2021-3156-4.patch: fix the memset offset when
      converting a v1 timestamp to TS_LOCKEXCL in
      plugins/sudoers/timestamp.c.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2021-3156-5.patch: don't assume that argv is
      allocated as a single flat buffer in src/parse_args.c.
    - CVE-2021-3156
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/sudo you're running the patched version which is no longer vulnerable.